# Unzip a file and save its content into a database

Tags: python, django

I am building a website using Django where the user can upload a .zip file. I do not know how many sub folders the file has or which type of files it contains.

I want to:

1) Unzip the file

2) Get all the file in the unzipped directory (which might contains nested sub folders)

3) Save these files (the content, not the path) into the database.

I managed to unzip the file and to output the files path.

**However** this is snot exactly what I want. Because I do not care about the file path but the file itself.
In addition, since I am saving the unzipped file into my `media/documents`, if different users upload different zip, and all the zip files are unzipped, the folder `media/documents` would be huge and it would impossible to know who uploaded what.

**Unzipping the .zip file**

```
    myFile = request.FILES.get('my_uploads')
    with ZipFile(myFile, 'r') as zipObj:
       zipObj.extractall('media/documents/')
```

**Getting path of file in subfolders**

```
    x = [i[2] for i in os.walk('media/documents/')]
    file_names = []
    for t in x:
        for f in t:
            file_names.append(f)
```

**views.py** # It is not perfect, it is just an idea. I am just debugging.

```
def homeupload(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        my_entity = Uploading()
        # my_entity.my_uploads = request.FILES["my_uploads"]
        myFile = request.FILES.get('my_uploads')
        with ZipFile(myFile, 'r') as zipObj:
           zipObj.extractall('media/documents/')

        x = [i[2] for i in os.walk('media/documents/')]
        file_names = []
        for t in x:
            for f in t:
                file_names.append(f)
        my_entity.save()
```

Comment: It's unclear, what you want to save into the database? Only filenames or content? What is your database scheme? Do you want to save each file with reference to a user?

Comment: Do you really need to call `ZipFile.extractall`? The class provides methods to access the files without extracting the whole thing to your filesystem. Look at `ZipFile.infolist` and `ZipFile.read`.

Comment: I need to save in the database the content of each file, not the path name. Ideally in reference with the main zip file.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't have to clutter up your filesystem when using a `ZipFile`, as it contains methods that allow you to read the files stored in the zip, directly to memory, and then you can save those objects to a database.

Specifically, we can use `.infolist()` or `.namelist()` to get a list of all the files in the zip, and `.read()` to actually get their contents:

```
with ZipFile(myFile, 'r') as zipObj:
    file_objects = [zipObj.read(item) for item in zipObj.namelist()]
```

Now `file_objects` is a list of `bytes` objects that have the content of all the files. I didn't bother saving the names or file paths because you said it was unneccessary, but that can be done too. To see what you can do, [check out what actually get's returned from](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipinfo-objects) `infolist`

If you want to save these `bytes` objects to your database, it's usually possible if your database can support it (most can). If you however wanted to get these files as plain text and not bytes, you just have to convert them first with something like `.decode`:

```
with ZipFile(myFile, 'r') as zipObj:
    file_objects = [zipObj.read(item).decode() for item in zipObj.namelist()]
```

Notice that we didn't save any files on our system at any point, so there's nothing to worry about a lot of user uploaded files cluttering up your system. However the database storage size on your disk **will** increase accordingly.